# Multiple image / orientation to PDF JavaScript

Tags: javascript, image, pdf

Is there any javascript way to convert 5 images to PDF allowing the pdf to have multiple orientations?

Like:

- page1: `portrait`
- page2: `portrait`
- page3: `landscape` <-------
- page4: `portrait`
- page5: `portrait`

To perform something like this:
[example.pdf](https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/files/4159445/Example.pdf)

---

**Edit:** *To people that are passing here*: jsPDF doesn't seem to be able to do it then I asked here: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2655 (waiting for an answer)

I found this lib there that make it: https://pdfkit.org/ (But less user-friendly)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[*Solved*]:** I tried with `pdfkit`, but it's a real mess to integrate in vuejs. I succeed with jsPDF after code looking, I answered myself here: https://github.com/MrRio/jsPDF/issues/2655

```js
var doc = new jsPDF({orientation: 'p'})
doc.addPage(null, 'p')
doc.addPage(null, 'l')
doc.addPage(null, 'p')
doc.addPage(null, 'p')
```